# Updating the sym column in a trade table

Tags: kdb, partition, database-partitioning

I would like to update my sym column in my trade table so that at the end of every sym there is a _1 appended onto the end of it.

I have tried `update sym:sym _ "_1" from trade` which gave me a `par` error so I then tried the `fncol` function from the `dbmaint.q` script which was

```
`fncol[`:path/to/hdb;`trade;`sym;,"_1]`
```

which also gave me an error on / which I'm not sure why. If anyone has any idea how to fix this or could point me in the right direction that would be great

Comment: Is the symbol used in other tables? Might be possible / suitable to update the global sym variable on disk instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not as trivial as it looks on paper due to the fact that it's an on-disk table (can't use `update` directly hence `par` error) and the sym column is possibly enumerated? (hence why you couldn't append string)

If the sym column is enumerated then they need to be re-enumerated after the "_1" is appended, something like:

```
load`:/path/to/mySymFile; /make sure sym file is loaded
fncol[`:path/to/hdb;`trade;`sym;{`:/path/to/mySymFile?`$string[x],\:"_1"}];
```

However personally I don't think this would be a great idea and you'd be polluting your sym file with a bunch of new symbols. Why not just append the "_1" at runtime? Does it have to be persisted?

If your sym column is actually a string column and not enumerated, then you would just need:

```
fncol[`:path/to/hdb;`trade;`sym;{x,\:"_1"}];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll give these a go, right now I'm having some trouble actually loading in my hdb I think theres something wrong with my sym file. I'm trying to create a performance profile from my data so I'm planning on copying my existing data and adding _1, _2 .. _9 to create trade and quote tables with 300 syms instead of just 30 and then write onto disk. I was just trying to make sure I can update it before I expand it to more. I was thinking of doing it one by one and then appending each table at the end to eachother, do you think this will work or is there a simpler way?

Comment: If you just want to append more dummy data then there's probably no need to modify the data already on disk, just upsert/append new data to disk. ` `:/path/to/db/2022.01.02/tab/ upsert .Q.en[\`:/path/to/db;<fabricated data>] `